# Paint brush hair identification

Tags: paint, paint-brushes

Years ago, when I was a schoolboy, I used this paint brush with natural hair looking bristles. It is from an Indian brand named Camlin. But these types of brushes are no longer available in the market even from the same brand. Does any one know what is the hair used (pic attached) and which brand has this still in production.[image]

Comment: Does the brush have any marks, any identification?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's **badger hair** - the grey-white gradations are typical for these kinds of brushes:

[image: Paint brush made of badger hair]

They are quite common, and many manufacturers produce them, including *Da Vinci*, *Isabey*, *Royal & Langnickel*, and *Raphael*.

> Unlike other hair, pure badger hair is thickest at the tips, giving
>   these brushes a bushy appearance. They're excellent for glazing
>   techniques, and popular with decorative and faux finish painters
>   because of their blending ability.  <sup>[source](https://www.dickblick.com/products/da-vinci-pure-badger-brushes/)</sup>

---

> Badger brushes are [..] more springy than bristle, and they have a
>   softer touch. They cost more but seem to last forever (I have some
>   which are twelve years and counting). <sup>[source](http://www.wetcanvas.com/forums/showthread.php?t=846)</sup>